# Lnk2001 error in VS2008

Tags: c++, linker

all
I am very new to C++.
But I have used C# as my primary develop language.
Now I have an application written in MFC.
When I first built it, it gives me those error.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: long __thiscall CWnd::SendMessageW(unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?SendMessageW@CWnd@@QAEJIIJ@Z) DbeCok.lib
```

Could someone give me a clue to fix this?

EDIT
The original message is below
    Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __stdcall AfxDeactivateActCtx(unsigned long,unsigned long)" (?AfxDeactivateActCtx@@YGHKK@Z)  C:\WebDev\SPC\DbeCok.lib(GridCellBase.obj)

Comment: Sounds like you forgot a lib. You'll need to a) add the folder where the lib is in Properties (of project) -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories, and then add the library name in Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Libraries

Comment: Go into the project properties and in the General section check and make sure that the option "Use of MFC" is set to either "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" or "Use MFC in a Static Library" . If it's not set to one of those the MFC libraries will not be automatically linked.

Comment: @Borgleader You mean "Additional Dependencies"? I added the libs.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It is already "Use MFC in a Static Library".